# How to format a date with slashes in C#

Tags: c#, date-format

When i write a date in C# by using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

then it returns `2010-09-10`, but I need `2010/09/10`. How do I make it output slashes?

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here.  Are you trying to convert a date with dashes into a date with slashes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Specify a culture. Your current culture uses - for the separators, and that's what ToString defaults to (your current culture), unless you override it.

You can try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but perhaps it would be better if you specified a different culture, for instance if you want the US culture:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Both of the above will give you / as a separator.

Comment: What namespace is `CultureInfo` in?

Comment: @aaron-franke `System.Globalization`

Answer (score 34):

Use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
```

/ - the date separator. It will be replaced according current culture.
So you need enclose it with char literal delimiter (') to use it like char.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

Comment: +1: Didn't know that you could override it like that!

Comment: You mean the char literal delimiter, not string.

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to specify the slashes as character literals:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
"2010/09/10"
```