# why does DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") give me dd-MM-yyyy?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want my datetime to be converted to a string that is in format "dd/MM/yyyy"

Whenever I convert it using `DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`, I get `dd-MM-yyyy` instead.

Is there some sort of culture info that I have to set?

Comment: do DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Comment: I did that, it didn't work, the problem isn't the dates, it's the "-", I want it to be a "/" like I've specified

Comment: use MM rather than mm - mm represents minutes and not months.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a date with slashes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684033/how-to-format-a-date-with-slashes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The [MSDN documentation for DateTime.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) is hopelessly wrong: "*For example, the “MM/dd/yyyyHH:mm” format string displays the date and time string in a fixed format ... The format string uses “/” as a fixed date separator regardless of culture-specific settings.*"

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Slash is a date delimiter, so that will use the current culture date delimiter.

If you want to hard-code it to always use slash, you can do something like this:

```
DateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
```

Comment: @spender - in some cultures they are.

Comment: You could also use this format: dateTime.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd")

Comment: MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

Comment: @DanielA.White There are countries that have more lefties than right handers ? I mean when I think about a slash with a sword (right hander normal) it makes a `/` :)

Comment: Another method I've encountered is : 
`string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now)`
Only problem is that it doesn't always work.
Worth trying though

Comment: Escaping the format string using backslash does also work: DateTime.Now.ToString("dd\\/MM\\/yyyy");

Comment: Life saving solution

Answer (score 77):

Pass [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the second parameter of DateTime, it will return the string as what you want, even a very special format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd|MM|yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

will return:
28|02|2014

Comment: This code is more clear, than in accepted answer (I mean added CultureInfo). It looks at least better than escaping slashes by apostrophes.

Comment: Definitely easier to read than using escape characters.  I'm a bit shocked that I didn't know the whole time that my date formats were going to get overwritten!

Answer (score 14):

Add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as an argument:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

var dateTime = new DateTime(2016,8,16);
dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Will return:

```
"16/08/2016"
```

Comment: if the developer uses tostring method with some letters like M m ss etc. will get wrong result with your solution
for example Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy/dd/mm/Month",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) will not result 2017/01/02/Month  it will result 2017/01/02/2onth

Comment: @OkanSARICA if you would want to suffix the date with ”/Month” you should do it after the ToString method instead. DateTime.Now.ToString(”yyyy/MM/dd”, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ”/Month”;

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVC, tables, it works like this:

```
<td>@(((DateTime)detalle.fec).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"))</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 @foreach (DataRow _Row in CashBook2.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@DateTime.Parse(_Row["Vou_Date"].ToString()).ToString(DateFormat)</td>
                    <td>@_Row["Vou_No"].ToString()</td>
                    <td>@_Row["Description"].ToString()</td>
                    <td>@decimal.Parse(_Row["DR"].ToString()).ToString(NumFormat)</td>
                    <td>@decimal.Parse(_Row["CR"].ToString()).ToString(NumFormat)</td>
                    <td>@Balance</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Comment: please provide some context for the code