# DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") returns invalid DateTime Value

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to get todays date in GBR format but,

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

returns with the value of `08/00/2013`

So `00` in the month group was returned instead of returning the month `04`.

Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: apparently it should be MM. mm is returning the minutes.

Comment: @DGibbs It shouldn't!

Comment: @JMK I typed it in as `"dd/MM/yyyy"'

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Lower `mm` means minutes, so

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

[**works**](http://ideone.com/7orxw4).

[**Standard Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Comment: Regarding the one who tried to edit my answer, the order  the days, month and year appears depends on the current culture. Thats why you have noticed a difference between the first and the other approaches. You can alway use a spefic culture, f.e. by using the overload of DateTime.ToString.

Comment: The only point I'd make with this solution is that these return 2 different formats when you have single digit day or month, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") gives you say 01/01/2017 where as the other two would give you 1/1/2017.

Answer (score 11):

use `MM`(months) instead of `mm`(minutes) :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more format options.

Answer (score 6):

It should be `MM` for months. You are asking for minutes.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Comment: hi, I am using the above code exactly, when executed from iis automaticaly date seperated using '-' instead of '/'. i have created a log for that to check the input. can you help me to solve this,  iis machine date format is dd/MM/yyyy only.

Comment: i set a value to the textbox      
Textbox.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 but it recognize as:    30-08-2016

Comment: i guess i found solution here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343289/why-does-datetime-tostringdd-mm-yyyy-give-me-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what the other answers have said, note that the '/' character in "dd/MM/yyyy" is not a literal character: it represents the date separator of the current user's culture. Therefore, if the current culture uses yyyy-MM-dd dates, then when you call toString it will give you a date such as "31-12-2016" (using dashes instead of slashes). To force it to use slashes, you need to escape that character:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")     --> "19-12-2016" for a Japanese user
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")     --> "19/12/2016" for a UK user
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd\\/MM\\/yyyy") --> "19/12/2016" independent of region
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `MM` for months. `mm` is for minutes.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You probably run this code at the begining an hour like (`00:00`, `05.00`, `18.00`) and `mm` gives minutes (`00`) to your datetime.

From [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

> "mm" --> The minute, from 00 through 59.
>
> "MM" --> The month, from 01 through 12.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/zZHAQP). (Which the *month* part of first line depends on which time do you run this code `;)` )

Answer (score 0):

There are only minor error.Use MM instead of mm ,so it will be effective 
 **write as below:**

```
 @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyy")
```