# Convert.ToDateTime('Datestring') to required dd-MM-yyyy format of date

Tags: c#

I have string of Date which can be in any format of date but I wanted to convert it to `dd-MM-yyyy` format.
I have tried every `Convert.ToDatetime` option which converts only to the System format. I want it to convert `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Please reply. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share the code for what you have done so far. Also, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876418/datetime-today-tostringdd-mm-yyyy-returns-invalid-datetime-value

Comment: can you share the output of your current date string ?

Comment: You have to create a user defined function for this, which will split the date string and return new generated date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Is it a string or a date? Please share the code

Comment: Does `new DateTime(yourString).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` not do it?

Comment: simply use `date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("YouDateString", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

This will return `DateTime` with your `Format`

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is not needed here as `DateTime.ParseExact` already return a DateTime object.

Answer (score 4):

Despite there being many answers and this being a duplicate answer, here are some possible solutions:

```
string formatted = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

or

```
string formatted = date.ToString("dd MM yyyy");
```

[This link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) might help you with more formats and options.

Comment: Here the problem is exactly opposite. To convert string of certain format to DateTime..

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) has an overloaded method to accepts multiple formats, include (all)possible formats you receive and parse the string. Once you get the valid `DateTime` you could apply desired format in converting to string.

```
  // ex...
  string dateString = ...;  // your date.

  string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                     "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                     "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                     "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
                     "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff" };

   var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);

  //convert to desired format.
  var strDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.Day + "/" + time.Month + "/" + time.Year);
```

//return: 22/05/2016