# Converting dd/MM/yyyy string format date to MM/dd/yyyy date format in ASP.NET Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert `dd/MM/yyyy` string format to `MM/dd/yyyy` date Format. In my form I want to show the date to user in `dd/mm/yyyy` for that I have done.

But I want convert `dd/MM/yyyy` string date to `MM/dd/yyyy` date format for Search date in database.

Please Help Me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert.ToDateTime('Datesrting') to required dd-MM-yyyy format of date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071415/convert-todatetimedatesrting-to-required-dd-mm-yyyy-format-of-date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dd/mm/yyyy formatted string to Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738608/converting-dd-mm-yyyy-formatted-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("YouDateString", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `dd/MM/yyyy` format string to datetime using `DateTime.ParseExact` then convert it back as `MM/dd/yyyy` format date string using `ToString()` method

```
string inp = "23/08/2016"; // inp is dd/MM/yyyy format date string
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(inp, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s1 = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // s1 is now MM/dd/yyyy format date string
```

or simply one expression

```
string s2 = DateTime.ParseExact("23/08/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: your answer is correct but i want convert in date time format

Comment: in datetime object there is no specific format, it will present you as your system format, to get datetime in specific format you need to convert it to a specific format string, try change your pc system datetime format then you will notice datetime object will show you using that format

Comment: There is an error when I try this approach: "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar"