# ASP.NET DateTime not converting properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have this date here:

```
DateTime RelevantDate = new DateTime(2017, 11, 13, 16, 0, 0, 0);

            request.RelevantDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RelevantDate.ToString("o"));
```

and I am expecting:

> 2017-11-13T16:00:00-05:00

Instead I am getting:

> 2017-11-13T16:00:00

This really needs to be in this format: 2017-11-13T16:00:00-05:00, how can I do that? request.RelevantDate is expecting DateTime

If I do this:

```
request.RelevantDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
```

it gives me the correct format:

> 2017-11-08T06:43:39-05:00

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071415/convert-todatetimedatestring-to-required-dd-mm-yyyy-format-of-date, look careful to this option: "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a `DateTime` using this constructor its `Kind` property is `Unspecified`, i.e. it is neither local nor UTC.

`DateTime.Now` returns an object with `DateTimeKind.Local`, which is why the time zone is added to the output of `.ToString("o")`.

You could use another constructor where you can explicitely set the kind to `Local`, e.g. `new DateTime(2017, 11, 13, 16, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)`.

This way the time zone will be appear in the output of `.ToString("o")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify timezone if you want to see timezone information in DateTime formatted string.

You can use this approach.
Please have a look on it:

If you want to use Local Time Zone

```
DateTime RelevantDate = new DateTime(2017, 11, 13, 16, 0, 0, 0);
var DateTimeWithZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(RelevantDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

If you want to use custom timezone

```
DateTime RelevantDate = new DateTime(2017, 11, 13, 16, 0, 0, 0);
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
var DateTimeWithZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(RelevantDate, timeZone);
```