# ASP.NET Core datepicker format gets ignored

Tags: html, date, asp.net-core, razor

Similiar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752832/format-date-within-view-in-asp-net-core-mvc) one. I have a datepicker field in an ASP.NET Core razor page which I would like to format in Germany-style: `dd.MM.yyyy` (14.05.2019). However, all my formatting seems to get ignored.

I have already this on my model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DateFilter { get; set; }
```

And this in my view:

```
<input asp-for="DateFilter" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" />
```

Nevertheless in Chrome the picker gets displayed as `MM/dd/yyyy`. In Edge it shows as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Chrome:

[image]

Edge:

[image]

I even tried to set the default culture in my Startup.cs with no effect

```
options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "de-DE", uiCulture: "de-DE");
```

Any ideas what I'm still missing? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value the format displayed in the browser is completely up to the browser and what the browser's locale is. The value submitted to the server will be in yyyy-mm-dd format though, regardless of the user's locale. `format` doesn't appear to be a valid `<input type="date">` attribute.

Comment: thanks guys! Yes, seems to be a duplicate. I didn't think of looking for the HTML part of the issue. Thought it was related to my ASP-side of things. Can close this one.