# .NET Core model date format not working - using Razor page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a model which has a date, when I run my code, it gives me `29/08/2019 00:00:00`. I want it to be `29/08/2019`

In my model, I have tried:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

and

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

but both seem to not work, I keep getting `29/08/2019 00:00:00`.

I am open to suggestions using the razor page but I do think it's easier to sort this out in the model.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358195/1296030

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] 
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

on the `Date` field.

It works well when I use below demo:

Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
public IList<Student> Student { get;set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Student = await _context.Students.ToListAsync();

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Student) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

            @*or below*@
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @Qwerty Could you accept my answer if it has resolved your problem.