# Datetime.ToString() C# not working as expected

Tags: c#, datetime

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) it seems like I can create my own format with `Datetime.ToString()` method by using `M, m, d, y` etc. But when I tried one it didn't worked as expected, snipped below is the issue.

[image]

I was expecting `7/29/2015` but received `7-29-2015` !!! why?

Comment: Because [`/` is the date separator configured on your system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator). Use `'/'` for a literal slash.

Comment: @Adil The difference is '-' and '/'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a date with slashes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684033/how-to-format-a-date-with-slashes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like your [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `-` and that's why `/` character replace itself to it.

[`"/"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator.*

You have a few options, you either escape it with single quotes (or `\/` in a verbatim string literal) or use a culture that has `/` as a `DateSeparator` like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy");
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"M\/d\/yyyy");
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: ohhhkkkk... thanks mate.. will accept when allowed soon.. :)

Comment: @yogi No. You can play around. A `/` in your string means "use the date separator of the format provider in question". However, `'/'` or `\/` means "include a literal slash". So either `"M'/'d'/'yyyy"` or `@"M\/d\/yyyy"` will be fine.